# Are these two circuits equivalent/same?

Tags: ac, dc, voltage-measurement

[image]

If we will take the voltage output from the dc source in both circuits will we get same voltage output ? Will the voltage drop across the capacitor will be same ?

Note: Upper end of AC source is positive and lower is negative initially.

Comment: What does KVL tell you, assume for simplicity the ac source is zero, the DC voltage across the capacitor isn't the same for both circuits.

Comment: Did you intend to have the DC source give different polarity in the two circuits?

Comment: no polarity for DC is same in the two circuits.

Comment: output voltage from dc will be same in both circuits?

Comment: If you mean the source polarity to be the same, please re-draw your schematics to show it that way. For most of us, the schematic is what defines the circuit you're trying to model.

Comment: What side is the positive terminal of dc source connected to of capacitor?  Are they the same?  That should help.

Comment: I edited and mentioned the polarity of ac source.

Comment: "polarity for DC is same in the two circuits" - Ignore the physical orientation of parts in the drawing. Trace the wire from the positive end of the DC source to the next component. Is it the same in both circuits, or different?

Comment: How do you get from the right capacitor terminal to the left terminal? In the first circuit: down through the battery voltage then add the sine. In the second circuit: up through the battery voltage then add the sine. Are these the same?